# What is Wrong With This Formula (Flow)?

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, process-builder

I am moving from process builder to Flow and I am trying to create a formula to be used. This formula works already in PB so why won't it work in Flow.

**I get the following error:**

> These issues prevent activation.
> OwnerID (Formula) - The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing '='

**Here is the formula:**

```
IF(
ISPICKVAL([Case].Account.VCC_Code__c,"CJ_SE"), "00G1C000004moS1UAI",
IF(
ISPICKVAL([Case].Account.VCC_Code__c,"CJ_DE"), "00G1C000004moRrUAI",
IF(
ISPICKVAL([Case].Account.VCC_Code__c,"CJ_ES"), "00G1C000004moRwUAI",
IF(
ISPICKVAL([Case].Account.VCC_Code__c,"CJ_FR"), "00G1C000004moRmUAI",
"00G1C000005AxE9UAK")
)))
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. You should show a screen shot from Flow where you are defining this formula. Also -- hardcoded recordtypeIds should be avoided. Flow has the ability to acquire recordtypeIds by using Get Records element or `$Record.Recordtype.DeveoperName`

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations! I will definitely take a look at the How to Ask section.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax in formulas will be different in Process Builder vs Flow. I can see here that the `[Case].Account.VCC_Code__c` syntax is not correct for flow. Assuming you're using a Record Triggered flow on the Case, the correct syntax would be `{!$Record.Account.VCC_Code__c}`.

To find the correct syntax for this type of thing, use the field directly above where you type the formula. It normally says `Insert a resource...`. You can search in that field for the value that you need and it will give you the correct syntax.

Beyond that, @croperedy's advice above is good. For readability, I would at a bare minimum replace those record ID's with resources of type 'Constant' and name them something like `CJ_SE_QUEUE` or whatever those record Ids represent. For readability, I also recommend indenting your nested IF statements.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response! I will implement those changes